# Странности с self.args при работе с объектами типа "исключение"

Tags: python

Анализируя работу с исключениями, наткнулся на вот такую ситуацию.
Берем пример который в разных видах гуляет по источникам и учебникам:

```
class UppercaseException(Exception):
    pass
words = ['я', 'ты', 'он', 'ОНА', 'оно']
for word in words:
        if word.isupper():
            raise UppercaseException (word)
```

Результат получаем ожидаемый:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-54-fc1eb7bb7c0c>", line 4, in <module>
    raise UppercaseException (word)

UppercaseException: ОНА
```

Ввожу конструктор класса. На случай, если мне в дальнейшем потребуется некоторая обработка в нем - ввожу определение нового атрибута:

```
class UppercaseException ( Exception ):
    def __init__(self, ar):
        print ('Обработка исключений')
        self.atr = ar
        return
words = ['я', 'ты', 'он', 'ОНА', 'оно']
for word in words:
        if word.isupper():
            raise UppercaseException (word)
```

Результат практически тождественен предыдущему:

```
Обработка исключений
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-55-b239d3ebd306>", line 10, in <module>
    raise UppercaseException (word)

UppercaseException: ОНА
```

Пока все понятно и ожидаемо.  А теперь - **собственно вопрос.** Изменяю **имя** атрибута:

```
class UppercaseException ( Exception ):
    def __init__(self, ar):
        print ('Обработка исключений')
        self.args = ar
        return
words = ['я', 'ты', 'он', 'ОНА', 'оно']
for word in words:
        if word.isupper():
            raise UppercaseException (word)
```

И результат меняется кардинально!

```
Обработка исключений
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-56-6460513f725f>", line 9, in <module>
    raise UppercaseException (word)

UppercaseException: ('О', 'Н', 'А')
```

Для облегчения анализа вывожу типы (ну и по ходу -  сами значения) внутри конструктора

```
class UppercaseException ( Exception ):
    def __init__(self, ar):
        print ('Входной параметр: ', type(ar),ar)
        self.args = ar
        print ('Атрибут класса: ', type(self.args),self.args)
        return
words = ['я', 'ты', 'он', 'ОНА', 'оно']
for word in words:
        if word.isupper():
            raise UppercaseException (word)
```

Обратите внимание как определяются типы:

```
Входной параметр:  <class 'str'> ОНА
Атрибут класса:  <class 'tuple'> ('О', 'Н', 'А')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-64-448db16a8ad8>", line 10, in <module>
    raise UppercaseException (word)

UppercaseException: ('О', 'Н', 'А')
```

Я даже могу предположить, что это *как-то* связано с тем, что класс `UppercaseException` наследуется от класса `Exception`. Но и это как-бы не должно влиять на тип переопределяемого атрибута, причем даже если  будет явно (!)  вызываться конструктор класса-родителя (при неявном вызове - ситуация аналогичная) :

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.args = tuple(a)
        print("class A: ",self.args,type(self.args))
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a):
        super().__init__( a)
        print("Параметр a :",a,type(a))
        self.args = a
        print("class B: ",self.args,type(self.args))        
b=B('qwerty')
```

Результат:

```
class A:  ('q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y') <class 'tuple'>
Параметр a : qwerty <class 'str'>
class B:  qwerty <class 'str'>
```

Тип как был строковым, так таким и остался, т.е. произошло именно *переопределение*. Как и ожидалось.

Может кто-то разбирался с этим вопросом, или имеет хоть какие-то предположение о том, что и почему происходит при работе с исключениями?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавим и изменим пару строк:

```
def __init__(self, ar):
    print ('На входе: ', type(self.args),self.args)           # Здесь
    print ('Входной параметр: ', type(ar),ar)
    self.newAr = ar                                           # И здесь
    print ('Атрибут класса: ', type(self.newAr),self.newAr)
    return
```

и получим

```
На входе:  <class 'tuple'> ('ОНА',)
Входной параметр:  <class 'str'> ОНА
Атрибут класса:  <class 'str'> ОНА
```

args определятся в родительском классе как tuple. И при вашем присвоении происходит преобразование. Никаких чудес

---

> [Built-in Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)
>
> exception BaseException
>
> args
>
> The tuple of arguments given to the exception constructor. Some
> built-in exceptions (like OSError) expect a certain number of
> arguments and assign a special meaning to the elements of this tuple,
> while others are usually called only with a single string giving an
> error message.

Comment: Да, но это к сожалению, не ответ на вопрос.  Более того -  это подтверждение моего вопроса. То, что так будет работать при любом другом имени атрибута -  я уже написал в вопросе. Мой вопрос как раз и качается  имени self.args. Формально ведь нет никакой информации (по крайней мере мне не встречалось) о специальном использовании этого имени именно в контексте обработки исключений. Если же это где-то указано в документации - буду благодарен за наводку.

Comment: С вашим рейтингом набрать в гугле "python 3 class Exception" и открыть первую же ссылку -  https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html   Base classes /  exception BaseException /
args - The tuple of arguments given to the exception constructor. Some built-in exceptions (like OSError) expect a certain number of arguments and assign a special meaning to the elements of this tuple, while others are usually called only with a single string giving an error message.

Comment: Еще раз. Я понимаю, что args - это один из атрибутов класса родителей (ну или кортеж аргументов). О чем и написал в вопросе.  Последний пример в вопросе - это ЯВНОЕ определение этого-же имени  как кортежа в классе родителе и тем не менее - в классе наследнике он остается строкой.  Т.о. поведение относиться не к наследованию как таковому, а к особенностям наследования при использования класса BaseException. Вот об этом и вопрос.

Comment: Смотрите - вы не вызываете родительский конструктор, но получаете на входе заполненный args. таким образом, для начала надо понять механизм создания вашего экземпляра. Это мне кажется интересней. А что касается вашего вопроса, вполне возможно, что там сеттер

Comment: Да, про сеттер -  похоже близко к истине. По крайней мере -  я нашел кое-какую информацию в англоязычном интернете на эту тему. Правда и там на уровне предположений и догадок. Просто другое вообще ничего в голову не приходит.